# compare two files matches a pattern and print

Tags: awk

I have two files input1.txt and input2.txt.

input1.txt has following details:

```
    abcd
    bcad
    cagh
    degh
    usna
```

input2.txt has following details:

```
abcd.dev.net ip: 169.254.0.2
bcad.prod.net ip: 169.254.0.3
cagh.uat.net ip: 169.254.0.4
us-1212-qwe.net ip: 169.254.232.50
us-cisco.net ip: 10.120.2.3
degh.stage.net ip: 169.254.0.5
usna.prod.net ip: 169.254.0.6
ab1234.net ip: 169.254.0.7
```

-   catorr.net ip: 169.254.0.8

I need to get the corresponding IP details of the servers listed in "input1.txt" from the file "input2.txt"

Output should be like this:

```
abcd.dev.net 169.254.0.2
bcad.prod.net 169.254.0.3
cagh.uat.net 169.254.0.4
degh.stage.net 169.254.0.5
usna.prod.net 169.254.0.6
```

Comment: this isn't a "make this for me" site, show us what you tried and your problem

Comment: Wonder this isn't really possible using awk.

Answer (score 1):

Would `grep` work:

```
grep -Fwf input1 input2


abcd.dev.net ip: 169.254.0.2
bcad.prod.net ip: 169.254.0.3
cagh.uat.net ip: 169.254.0.4
degh.stage.net ip: 169.254.0.5
usna.prod.net ip: 169.254.0.6
```

Comment: note that this will match any match, not necessarily the intended position.

Comment: That is true, good point :).... made the `grep` option better I hope :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you want to join only until the first period you can use this

```
$ join -t. input1 <(sort input2)

abcd.dev.net ip: 169.254.0.2
bcad.prod.net ip: 169.254.0.3
cagh.uat.net ip: 169.254.0.4
degh.stage.net ip: 169.254.0.5
usna.prod.net ip: 169.254.0.6
```

if input1 is not sorted, do the same `<(sort input1)`